# How to Webscrape Data from an Interactive Chart on a Webpage?

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping

I am wondering whether it is possible to extract data (highest hour, daily average, March 2016 to March 2021) from the following interactive chart: [Image of Chart: Bangkok-PM2.5 - Long-term History (daily averages)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78xke.png)

The Website that contains the chart: http://berkeleyearth.lbl.gov/air-quality/local/Thailand/Bangkok

Then I would like to create a data frame in R with the extracted data from the chart.

Please let me know whether it is possible to do this, thank you in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to grab the data points that make up the chart. You'd need to have access to the raw data in tabular form from somewhere. the `rvest` package is the go to package for webscraping. A site may also provide an API to grab the data directly without the webscraping efforts, but that depends on the provider.

Comment: What is the website?

Comment: Hi Tom, the website where the interactive chart is located: http://berkeleyearth.lbl.gov/air-quality/local/Thailand/Bangkok 

The chart is labelled on the page as: Bangkok-PM2.5 - Long-term History (daily averages)

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you a list of all the data on the page

```
url <- "http://berkeleyearth.lbl.gov/air-quality/maps/cities/Thailand/Bangkok/Bangkok.json"

all_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
```

The historical data for daily average, maximum and minimum temperatures can be found in the following ugly list:

```
all_data$day_data
```

I'll leave the data manipulation and plotting up to you...